# Dynamic resizing of an element between the bottom of a webpage and close to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic

I'm trying to get an iframe to dynamically resize 150px from the top of a webpage, and go down to the bottom of the webpage, no matter what height someone's browser is. The width and height of the body are both set to 100% with overflow hidden.

If my question still doesn't make sense [here are some visuals](http://goawaymom.com/home.html)
The iframe should always be at the bottom and 150px from top- and you should always be able to see the content of the bottom element within the iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a Jquery solution:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YV3Bu/)

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var winHeight = $(window).height();

var frameHeight = winHeight - 150;

$("#frame").css("height",frameHeight+"px");

});
```

HTML - css

```
<iframe id="frame" src="http://goawaymom.com/messages.html"  />

#frame{
position:fixed;
top:150px;
overflow-x:scroll;

}
```

The #frame position does not need to be fixed!

Also I would advise wrapping it as a function and firing on window resize like so:

```
$(window).resize(function(){

whateverYouCalledIt();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$(window).dimension();` to get the dimension of the window. Use `$("#my_iframe").css();` to set the height and width.

Comment: Hey I don't know jquery and i'm curious to do this how could you do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a non-js solution, try wrapping the iframe into a div and use the css:

```
div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
iframe{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: it works, I just tried it on the demo page from the question. You need to disable the current rules on the iframe, though.